# how to convert PDF to HTMLConversion

Tags: java, pdfbox

I wanted to convert PDF to HTML in most efficient way.

input will be pdf in base 64 format and output should be html.
Any good open sources also ok

Can any1 help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [PDFBox](http://java.dzone.com/articles/converting-pdf-html-using?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29)?

Comment: This is what i am using but it does line by line conversion which is not optimal